# Apple watch standup detection

Tags: ios, watchkit, core-motion

I am now working on a app dealing with user's motion on the Apple watch. As shown on the Apple Watch, it recognize when you are sitting or standing. Is there any way to get access to it using API? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to obtain the type of motion using [CMMotionActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivity_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013502), which is part of the Core Motion Framework (introduced in watchOS 2.0).